# Ignore Column Table not working in Data Migration tool

Tags: magento2, migration

i add a custom column to my Magento 2 `quote` column which is `shipping_delivery_date`

i got a warning error when i migrate the data:

```
[2020-02-27 02:37:24][WARNING]: Destination fields are not mapped. Document: quote. Fields: shipping_delivery_date
```

i tried to ignore this column using map.xml file:

```
  <destination>
    ........   
    <field_rules>
        .......
        <ignore>
            <document>quote.shipping_delivery_date</document>
        </ignore>
    </field_rules>
  </destination>
```

but i still got the same warning

Comment: your added the ignore column map.xml ??

Comment: @MohitPatel yes

Comment: Please check my answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please add the code your **map.xml** file hope work this code

```
<destination>
    <field_rules>
            <ignore>
                <field>quote.shipping_delivery_date</field>
            </ignore>
    </field_rules>
</destination>
```

Comment: didnt you see my question?

Comment: you add the document tag code <document>quote.shipping_delivery_date</document> 
but i think add the field tag code 
<field>quote.shipping_delivery_date</field>
Please try this code after command data migration

Comment: sorry i didnt see that

Answer (score 1):

you can try below file

```
etc/xyz/magentoverison/map.xml.dist
```